# Can two separate computers connect over 127.X.X.X IP range?

Tags: ip, route-table

Is it possible to set two computers (each have one lan interface) to communicate over 127.X.X.X IP range (e.g. one PC 127.15.0.1 and the other 127.15.0.2)

```
+-----------+127.15.0.1+-----------+
| MyPC      | <------- | YourPC    |
|           |          |           |
| 127.15.0.1| -------> | 127.15.0.2|
+-----------+127.15.0.2+-----------+
  |       ^              |       ^
  |       |              |       |
127.0.0.1-+            127.0.0.1-+
```

for example if both are running Linux, would it be possible to say "ssh user@127.15.0.2" from the PC with address 127.15.0.1 ?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's generally not possible.

127.0.0.0/8 is local to a host only, see [RFC 1122](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1122). None of those addresses can be used over a physical link.

If you're looking for a *link-local* address, that's 169.254.0.0/16 for IPv4, without 169.254.0.0/24 and 169.254.255.0/24.

Otherwise you can use any range from [RFC 1918](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1918) for routable, private addresses.